# Heroku clock process - setting hours and minutes

Tags: python, heroku, clock, schedule

I'm looking to use the clock process in Heroku with my Python code.  The code I am using for clock.py is given as:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=14)
def scheduled_job():
    import AME_Heroku_v001.py

sched.start()
```

The above code runs the AME_Heroku_v001.py code every day between Monday and Friday at 1400 hours (2pm).  How would I write the above so that the code runs at 1430 hours (2:30pm)?

I have tried to incorporate 30 minutes into the code:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=14, minutes=30)
def scheduled_job():
    import AME_Heroku_v001.py

sched.start()
```

However this didn't seem to work.

Comment: What does "didn't seem to work" mean? Does it still fire, but at 2pm instead of 2:30? Do you get an error message? Did you commit the change and redeploy to Heroku?

Comment: Hi Chris!  When I only include "hour=14" in my code it ran at 2pm (as expected).  However, when I tried to include minutes=30, the code did not run.  Nothing else in my code was changed.